# QToolButton with icon + text: How to center both?

Tags: qt, qt5, text-alignment, qstyle, qstylesheet

I am using multiple [QToolButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html)s in a custom [QGridLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QGridLayout.html) widget. The buttons are set to display icon + text based on an assigned default QAction. The only issue is that the content (icon + text) is always left-aligned.

The content (icon + text, marked as a red box in the screenshot), should be center in the button (indicated by the blue box).

[image]

For most cases this is just fine, given that Qt automatically tries to render that button with the minimal size. However I am stretching the button to fit nicely into my QGridLayout.

```
QToolButton* pButton = new QToolButton(0);
pButton->addDefaultAction(pAction);
pButton->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon);
pButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);

QGridLayout *pActionAreaLayout = new QGridLayout;
pActionAreaLayout->addWidget(pSomeOtherWidget, 0, 0, 1, 2);
pActionAreaLayout->addWidget(pButton , 1, 0, 1, 1);
```

Is there a way to force the content to be centered in the button?

*PS: I found the following comment in [another forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/60893-Align-text-and-icon-of-QToolButton-on-center?p=269529#post269529), which however seems quite invasive and is not really clear to me yet:*

> You can try doing the horizontal alignment using a stylesheet, but you probably have to implement a QStyle proxy and reimplement drawControl() for QStyle::CE_ToolButtonLabel
>   Or derive from QToolButton, overwrite paintEvent() and call the style for everything other than the label.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: @user2672165: I edited in the code into the question. Not sure if that helps though in this case...

Comment: What about using the alignment in `void QGridLayout::​addWidget(QWidget * widget, int row, int column, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0)`? Also you could perhaps post a picture on how it looks and how you would like it to look because there are several parameters to consider?

Comment: @user2672165 I probably did not make it clear enough: The grid layout is not the issue. The button is perfectly placed and ([almost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515953/qtoolbutton-with-text-overwrite-minimal-height-to-minic-regular-button-height)) perfectly sized. The issue I have is that the content inside the button is not centered. See the screenshot I added to the question.

Comment: Ok. I think I understood that. I would try modifying pButton->layout(). The QToolButton ought to have a QHBoxLayout.

Comment: @user2672165 The button does not return a valid layout pointer. So unfortunately, there seems to be no layout that I could modify.

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier - you will probably have to reimplement a `QStyle` to change the alignment. Such things are usually "hard-coded" for a particular UI style. That's just how `QWidgets` are - not very flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suggest in answer to you another question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28630318/1917249  Do not use QToolButton, just use QPushButton, and add popup menu if needed.

Then you wont have different sizes of `QToolButton` and `QPushButton` widgets. And you will have centered icon and text.

Popupmenu can be easily added to QPushButton ( only small arrow wont be shown )

```
QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton(toolAction->icon(), "PushButton", window);
// window - widget where button is placed ( to get correct QMenu position )
QObject::connect(pushButton, &QPushButton::released, [window, pushButton, action](){
    QMenu menu;
    menu.addAction(action);
    QPoint pos = window->mapToGlobal(pushButton3->pos());
    pos += QPoint(0, pushButton->height());
    menu.exec(pos);
 });
```

Or you can subclass `QPushButton` and add Popup menu handling there. Much better then try to center text with icon in `QToolButton` or have in same size of `QPushButton` and `QToolButton`

For complex example please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28630318/1917249

Comment: The reasoning behind attempting to go for QToolButton as opposed to QPushButton was that a QToolButton automatically takes over the action attributes (title text + icon) and handles the signal / slot linking. But in the end those benefits are not worth the hassle and drawbacks I experienced in terms of button height and text / icon alignment. I therefore switched to QPushButton and manually set the text / icon attribute and setup the slot / signal linking.

Answer (score 1):

The following class does the job for me:

```
class CenteredToolButtonStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
CenteredToolButtonStyle(QToolButton* b, const QSize& sIcon);

virtual void drawItemPixmap(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int, const QPixmap &pixmap) const
    override { m_pic = pixmap; m_ny = rect.y(); Draw(painter); }
virtual void drawItemText(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int flags, const QPalette &pal, bool enabled,
    const QString &text, QPalette::ColorRole textRole = QPalette::NoRole) const override;
void Draw(QPainter *painter) const;

const QToolButton* B;
const QSize SICON;
mutable QString m_s;
mutable QPixmap m_pic;
mutable QRect m_r;
mutable int m_nf, m_ny;
mutable bool m_bEnabled;
mutable QPalette m_pal;
mutable QPalette::ColorRole m_textRole;
};


CenteredToolButtonStyle::CenteredToolButtonStyle(QToolButton* b, const QSize& sIcon)
: QProxyStyle(), B(b), SICON(sIcon), m_nf(0), m_bEnabled(true), m_ny(0)
{
b->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextBesideIcon);
setParent(b);
}

void CenteredToolButtonStyle::drawItemText(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int flags, const QPalette &pal,
bool enabled, const QString &text, QPalette::ColorRole textRole/* = QPalette::NoRole*/) const
{
m_s = text;
m_r = rect;
m_nf = flags | Qt::AlignCenter;
m_bEnabled = enabled;
m_pal = pal;
m_textRole = textRole;
Draw(painter);
}

void CenteredToolButtonStyle::Draw(QPainter *painter) const
{
if (m_ny) {
    if (m_r.y() != m_ny) return;
    auto r = m_r;
    r.adjust(-SICON.width() - 8, m_ny = 0, -itemTextRect(B->fontMetrics(), m_r, m_nf, m_bEnabled, m_s).width(), 0);
    QProxyStyle::drawItemPixmap(painter, r, Qt::AlignCenter, m_pic);
}
QProxyStyle::drawItemText(painter, m_r, m_nf, m_pal, m_bEnabled, m_s, m_textRole);
}
```

Sample use:

```
foreach(auto b, ui.mainToolBar->findChildren<QToolButton*>()) 
    b->setStyle(new CenteredToolButtonStyle(b, ui.mainToolBar->iconSize()));
```